# Getting past date results in future date

Tags: java

I have code:

```
java.util.Date purgeBackDate = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 390));
System.out.println(purgeBackDate);
```

I was expecting to print the date for 390 days ago, but instead, it prints a future date:`Fri Aug 21 05:57:11 EDT 2015`

I also tried to replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `new java.util.Date().getTime()`, and I am getting the same result. I am very confused because minus from the millisec used to work before.

I am using JDK 1.6 and 1.7 (both give this result): [Test Code](http://goo.gl/Q681vW)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your multiplication is all with `int`s and is overflowing to a negative number, which, when subtracted, yields a date in the future.

Cast the `1000` to `long` or use a `long` literal `1000L` to use a much wider valid number range and to get the correct number to subtract, and you'll get a date in the past.

Comment: it solves the problem, but it is not a good approach to deal with milliseconds by yourself if just a date is required.

Answer (score 2):

try Calendar instead:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -390);
```